# Windows 10 wrong credentials used to access samba server

Tags: windows, samba

Running Windows 10 build 19044.2006 (with previous this was working fine) I want to mount a remote shared folder that is on a Debian Samba server:

```
//server/folder

got the prompt for credentials (user:giacomino and its password) > press OK > got again the prompt
```

Looking on server side log I see that currently inserted credentials are ignored and replaced with those:

```
[2022/10/13 13:43:46.829803,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:509(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[WLF5] domain=[WWF5] workstation=[WWF5] len1=24 len2=248
[2022/10/13 13:43:46.829869,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:200(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [WWF5]\[WLF5]@[WWF5] with the new password interface
[2022/10/13 13:43:46.829892,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:203(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [WWF5]\[WLF5]@[WWF5]
[2022/10/13 13:43:46.829969,  3] ../../source3/auth/check_samsec.c:398(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'WLF5' in passdb.
[2022/10/13 13:43:46.829997,  2] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:344(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [WLF5] -> [WLF5] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER, authoritative=1
```

> WWF5 is the hostname, WLF5 is the windows user.

Why Windows send it's user insead of giacomino?

```
ii  samba                                  2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3         amd64        SMB/CIFS file, print, and login server for Unix
ii  samba-common                           2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3         all          common files used by both the Samba server and client
ii  samba-common-bin                       2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3         amd64        Samba common files used by both the server and the client
ii  samba-dsdb-modules:amd64               2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3         amd64        Samba Directory Services Database
ii  samba-libs:amd64                       2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3         amd64        Samba core libraries
ii  samba-vfs-modules:amd64                2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u3         amd64        Samba Virtual FileSystem plugins
```

Comment: please share the commands you try

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter in the username text box: YOURDOMAIN\User